# Table to Excel Arcpy Error

Tags: arcpy, excel, error-000732, error-000814

I am trying to export a point shapefile to an Excel sheet using the

```
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(FinalClipOutput, ExcelOut, "", "")
```

The "FinalClipOutput" is the result of a clip that happens earlier in the in process and the output shape is produced.

However when it tried to export that shape to Excel table I receive the following error:

> ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset
>   C:\Users\AFoddy\Desktop\Working\mycalc does not exist or is not
>   supported ERROR 000814: Invalid file type Failed to execute
>   (TableToExcel).

If I take the "mycalc" shapefile and use Table to Excel tool separately it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `FinalClipOutput` variable is set to "C:\Users\AFoddy\Desktop\Working\mycalc" when you use the TableToExcel_conversion tool.

That does not look like either of the most likely input types which I think would be a file geodatabase table or a dBase (*.dbf) file so I think you should double check what it is.

Perhaps you intended it to be "C:\Users\AFoddy\Desktop\Working\mycalc.dbf" or maybe "C:\Users\AFoddy\Desktop\Working.gdb\mycalc".

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing "FinalClipOutput" corresponds to the path in which your file is located without including its filename. If this is the case, you should add it at the end resulting in something like: "C:\Users\AFoddy\Desktop\Working\mycalc\FinalClipOutput.shp or a similar compatible file apart from .shp.

Also make sure you are using raw strings with r"C:\mypath"